# Simulating Data on (Y1, Y2) where Y2 has missing values

Tags: r, simulation, distribution, missing-data

Consider a two variable (Y<sub>1</sub>, Y<sub>2</sub>) problem, with each variable defined as follows:

- Y<sub>1</sub> = 1 + Z<sub>1</sub>, and Y<sub>1</sub> is fully observed
- Y<sub>2</sub> = 5 + 2*(Z<sub>1</sub>) + Z<sub>2</sub>, and Y<sub>2</sub> is missing if 2*(Y<sub>1</sub> − 1) + Z<sub>3</sub> < 0
- Z<sub>1</sub>, Z<sub>2</sub>, and Z<sub>3</sub> follow independent standard normal distributions.

How would we go about simulating a (complete) dataset of size 500 on (Y<sub>1</sub>, Y<sub>2</sub>)? This is what I wrote below:

```r
    n <- 500
    y <- rnorm(n)
```

How would we simulate the corresponding observed dataset (by imposing missingness
on Y<sub>2</sub>)? I'm not sure where to go with this question.

```r
    n <- 500
    z1 <- rnorm(n)
    z2 <- rnorm(n)
    z3 <- rnorm(n)

    y1 <- 1 + z1
    y2 <- 5 + 2*z1 + z2
```

Display the marginal distribution of Y<sub>2</sub> for the complete (as originally simulated) and observed (after imposing missingness) data.

Comment: You almost have it. You just need to replace the values of Y2 satisfying the condition with `NA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to display the distributions, in addition to the great explanation of **@jay.sf** is building the missing data mechanism in a new variable and compare both `y2` and `y2_missing`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(123)
#Data
n <- 500
#Random vars
z1 <- rnorm(n)
z2 <- rnorm(n)
z3 <- rnorm(n)
#Design Y1 and Y2
y1 <- 1+z1
y2 = 5 + 2*(z1) + z2
#For missing
y2_missing <- y2
#Set missing
index <- which(((2*(y1-1))+z3)<0)
y2_missing[index]<-NA
#Complete dataset
df <- data.frame(y1,y2,y2_missing)
#Plot distributions
df %>% select(-y1) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=value,fill=name))+
  geom_density(alpha=0.5)+
  ggtitle('Distribution for y2 and y2_missing')+
  labs(fill='Variable')+
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to include an error term in your data simulations, so another vector with mean zero should be included in the equation using again `rnorm(n)`.

```
seed <- sample(1:1e3, 1)

set.seed(635)  ## for sake of reproducibility

n <- 500
z1 <- rnorm(n)
z2 <- rnorm(n)
```

To get the missings you may sample a percentage of the vector and set it `NA`.

```
y2 <- 5 + 2*z1 + z2 + rnorm(n)  ## add error term independent of the `z`s

pct.mis <- .1  ## percentage missings
y2[sample(length(y2), length(y2)*pct.mis)] <- NA

## check 1: resulting missings
prop.table(table(is.na(y2)))
# FALSE  TRUE 
#   0.9   0.1 

summary(y2)
#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
# -2.627   3.372   5.123   4.995   6.643  13.653      50

## check 2: rounded coefficients resemble equation
fit <- lm(y2 ~ z1 + z2)
round(fit$coe)
# (Intercept)          z1          z2 
#           5           2           1 

## check 3: number of fitted values equals number of non-missing obs.
length(fit$fitted.values) / length(y2)
# [1] 0.9
```